# get count with hasMany not working yii2

Tags: count, yii2

I have CLub model (clubs) hasMany with User model like

Club n-n User

and I have UserClub model with columns: `id, club_id, user_id,` etc

In Club model

```
public function getCountUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserClub::className(), ['club_id'=>'id'])->count();
}
```

I wanna count all User on Club as code:

```
$query = Club::find()
    ->joinWith(['countUsers']);
    // ->with('countUsers');
    ->all();
```

so it is not working and throwing an error

> ```
> Club has no relation named \"countUsers\"."
> ```

Comment: what do you want a count or a query to join with relation?

Comment: updated the answer see the **EDIT2** section i think that is what you were asking hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Because it isn't a relation as it does not return a model object or an array of model objects, instead you are using `->count()` that makes it return a string that contains the total count for the user against the club.

If you are looking to get a count for the users against all the `Clubs` you can use the currently defined relation like `$club->countUser` see below.

```
$clubs=Club::find()->all();

foreach($clubs as $club){
    echo $club->countUser;
}
```

or change the relation to

```
public function getCountUser(){
    return $this->hasMany(UserClub::className(), ['club_id'=>'id']);
}
```

and use it like

```
$clubs=Club::find()->all();
foreach($clubs as $club){
    echo count($club->countUser);
}
```

or like below

```
$clubs=Club::find()->all();
foreach($clubs as $club){
    echo $club->getCountUser()->count();
}
```

## `EDIT`

You are actually trying to transform the following query using `ActiveRecord` as far as I understood from the discussion.

```
SELECT clubs.id, count(user_clubs.id) as total 
FROM 
clubs 
left join user_clubs on clubs.id = user_clubs.club_id 
group by clubs.id
```

if that is correct you can use the following

```
Clubs::find ()
        ->alias ( 'c' )
        ->select ( [ new \yii\db\Expression ( 'c.[[id]], count(uc.[[id]]) as total' ) ] )
        ->leftJoin ( '{{%user_clubs}} uc' , 'uc.club_id=c.id' )
        ->groupBy ( 'c.id' )
        ->all ();
```

***Note : You have to do one more thing you have to add a `public` property `$total` inside your `Club` model and add it to `safe` rules, because you are selecting the count as an alias `total` and until unless you define it inside the model the result set won't show you the count, so add the following inside the `Club` model.***

```
public $total;
```

under rules

```
[[other fields...,'total'] , 'safe' ] ,
```

## `EDIT2`

For some reason, I have a feeling that you are trying to count by specifying a relation instead of specifying the `->leftJoin ()` with the table `user_clubs`  in the query.

If that is so then you have to change your relation `getUserCount()` you should better give a meaningful name that describes it. i would rename it to `getClubUsers()`

```
public function getClubUsers(){
    return $this->hasMany(UserClub::className(), ['club_id'=>'id']);
}
```

After this, you still have to declare a public property `$total` as I described before inside your `Club` model, and add it to `safe` rules.

Now you can write your query in the following way

```
Clubs::find ()
    ->alias ( 'c' )
    ->select ( [ new \yii\db\Expression ( 'c.[[id]], count(cu.[[id]]) as total' ) ] )
    ->joinWith( ['clubUsers cu'] )
    ->groupBy ( 'c.id' )
    ->all ();
```

Comment: I don't want to foreach for that query. Here is my Query

```SELECT clubs.id, count(user_clubs.id) as total
FROM clubs
left join user_clubs on clubs.id = user_clubs.club_id
group by clubs.id```

how to use related on Yii2 like above query

Comment: without using foreach how are you going to display all the clubs? or maybe you are trying to say something else @VoTienHung

Comment: I just want to show count all users via club and get club info.

Comment: @VoTienHung see the edit section i just transformed  the query to `ActiveRecord`

Comment: Thanks for responding, but can't count them via hasMany?

Comment: dude you decide what you want i tyold you all possible options

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170736/discussion-between-vo-tien-hung-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).

Comment: sorry couldn't attend as had to go office, thought i had given enough clue to solve it. were you able to solve it? @VoTienHung

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with join, in my case i get users who have more than 0 referrals.

```html
$users = User::find()->with('referrals')
            ->from(User::tableName() . ' t')
            ->join('left join',User::tableName().' r','r.Deeplink = t.ReferralID')
            ->select('t.*,count(r.ID) as ct')
            ->groupBy('t.ID')
            ->andFilterHaving(['>','ct',0])
            ->all();
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi your relation is correct check you error **`Club has no relation named \"countUsers\"."`**

Means you are calling  a relation which not exist :
change query like this, **Relation name should be in Club Model**

```
public function getCount(){
 return $this->hasMany(UserClub::className(), ['club_id'=>'id']);
}



$clubs=Club::find()->all();
foreach($clubs as $club){
    echo count($club->getCount);
}


$query = Club::find()
    ->joinWith(['count']);
    // ->with('countusers');
    ->all();
```

If you want count just  do like this .
Load  the Club model .

```
$club_model =  Club::find()
$count = club_model->count;
```

Comment: count method do not work with relation with hasMany.